# Insert SVG images using Media Manager

Tags: svg, joomla, joomla3.0

I am using Joomla 3.9.12 for my client's website redesign and I am wanting to use SVG icons for some of the menu items. I have placed the SVG images in a specific image directory, but I cannot select them using the media manager popup that is launched by the "Link Image" option. I have updated the Media Manager configuration settings with the following:

Legal Extensions (File Types): bmp,csv,doc,gif,ico,jpg,jpeg,odg,odp,ods,odt,pdf,png,ppt,svg,swf,txt,xcf,xls,BMP,CSV,DOC,GIF,ICO,JPG,JPEG,ODG,ODP,ODS,ODT,PDF,PNG,PPT,SVG,SWF,TXT,XCF,XLS

Legal Image Extensions (File Types): bmp,gif,jpg,png,svg

Legal MIME Types: image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png,image/bmp,image/svg,application/x-shockwave-flash,application/msword,application/excel,application/pdf,application/powerpoint,text/plain,application/x-zip

I have also added AddType image/svg+xml .svg .svgz and AddEncoding gzip svgz to my htaccess file.

None of these changes have allowed the SVG images to be selected using the Media Manager. Why are we in 2019 and still having no possible way to add SVG images to Joomla? Is it still that big of a security concern?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using JCE as your text editor, try going to 
Components > JCE > Editor Profiles > Your Profile > Plugin Parameters > File Browser > Permitted File Extensions. Scroll to the images block and check if the SVG format is there. If it isn't, add SVG, save and try again.

If you still don't have any success, FTP to your images directory and double-check that the SVG file was successfully uploaded.

If you are using an editor other than JCE, look for a similar setting, or let us know what you are using.

Good luck!